# Post-processing wrf output in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use python to post-process WRF output. The various scripts I have seen are too complicated for my elementary level of python. I managed to put together bits of code from here and there. However in my final plot i am not able to capture the data properly.
I would appreciate any assistance.
My code is below
The two lines which gives the wrong results are:

```
cs=m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, baseArray, shading='flat', latlon=True)

#cs=m.contourf(lons, lats, baseArray, shading='flat', latlon=True)
```

Obviously my definition of the z component to contour

```
baseArray = np.fromfunction(lambda y,x: (1000.0 / (width + height)) * (y+x), (height, width), dtype = float)
```

is incorrect.

I will appreciate assistance to define my variable so that what is plotted reflects what is in the input file.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

fh = Dataset("wrfout_d01_2019-03-28_00:00:00", mode="r")
lons = fh.variables["XLONG"][:]
lats = fh.variables["XLAT"][:]
temp = fh.variables["T2"][:]
temp_units = fh.variables['T2'].units

fh.close()

# define map extent
lllon,lllat,urlon,urlat = 17.25,-21.90,38.44,-04.07

width = 300
height = 200

dlon = (urlon-lllon) / width
dLat = (urlat-lllat) / height
baseArray = np.fromfunction(lambda y,x: (1000.0 / (width + height)) * (y+x), (height, width), dtype = float)

lons = np.arange(lllon, urlon, dlon)
lats = np.arange(lllat, urlat, dLat)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

fig = plt.figure()

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(
projection = 'merc',
llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,resolution='h')

# Plot Data
cs=m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, baseArray, shading='flat', latlon=True)
#cs=m.contourf(lons, lats, baseArray, shading='flat', latlon=True)

# Add Grid Lines
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80., 81., 5.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 5.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10)

# Add Coastlines, States, and Country Boundaries
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

# Add Colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar(cs ,shrink=1.0) #, extend='both')

# Add Title
plt.title("Temperature")

plt.savefig("Temp2s.png" , format="png", dpi=300, transparent=True)

plt.show()
```

The following is code which is close to what should work. With this code, I have a problem with the numpy arrays of my longitude (x) and latitude (y). I hope someone conversant with numpy can assist me. I have added numpy in the tags.
This code gives me the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (17,60,69) (17,60)
```

What I know is that I have 69 points in x-direction and 60 in y-direction. My data file has 19 levels, and 9 time steps. I do not know where 17 comes 
from.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

fh = Dataset("wrfout_d01_2019-03-28_00:00:00", mode="r")
lons = fh.variables["XLONG"][:]
lats = fh.variables["XLAT"][:]
data = fh.variables["T2"][:]
data_units = fh.variables['T2'].units

fh.close()

# define map extent
lllon,lllat,urlon,urlat =  17.25,-21.90,38.44,-04.07

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(
    projection = 'merc', \
    llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, \
    urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat, resolution='h')

# Add Coastlines, States, and Country Boundaries
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

# Add Grid Lines
# draw parallels.
parallels = np.arange(0.,90,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)

# draw meridians
meridians = np.arange(180.,360.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)

 x,y = m(lons, lats) # compute map proj coordinates.

# draw filled contours.
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data)

# Add Colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar(cs ,shrink=1.0) #, extend='both')

# Add Title
plt.title("Surface Temperature")

plt.savefig("Temp2.png" , format="png", dpi=300, transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Zilore, are you just trying to plot temperature? And what line do you get your error? Can you print the shape of data?

Comment: Thanks @ BenT, when I give the commands in my script "print(lons.shape)", "print(lats.shape)", "print(data.shape)" I get (17,60,69) for all the three. I was expecting lons and lats to be one dimensional and data to be 2 dimensional, i.e. data(lons,lats). I do not understand the shape of lons, lats being (17,60,69). I wished I could send my data file,

Comment: Your lat,lons in wrf will be 3D in `(time, x,y)` because your grid may not be uniform and you can also have moving nests in wrf. Since in your example you are plotting the temperature at 2 meters you won't have the height component, so if you index all the arrays be a specific time it should work. You can also do a `ncdump -h` on your output file to help understand what is in the wrf output.

Comment: Once more thanks @BenT, your hint on indexing the array to a specific time worked. The lines which made this work are: lons = fh.variables["XLONG"][0][0][:], lats = fh.variables["XLONG"][0][:][0], data = fh.variables["T2"][0][:]. My code works perfectly. I have compared the output with that from grads, no difference, apart from color scheme which I need to improve in python. My appreciation.

Comment: Your welcome! I use python to process my own WRF data, I find it easier than using some of the ncar packages a majority of the time and allows for allot more customization.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of Python WRF processing packages worth looking into for plotting and analysis. They're both fairly straightforward to use:

- [wrf-python](https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (from NCAR)
- [salem](https://salem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)